# How to install bitnami wordpress inside a subdirectory of bitnami wordpress?

Tags: wordpress, ubuntu, bitnami

I have a website hosted on www.example.com that is a Bitnami application.
I want to install another bitnami wordpress on the same server that should be accessible on www.example.com/blog.
How to do this?

Answer (score 1):

You can install more than one WordPress module on a Bitnami stack. Download it from the [Bitnami website](https://bitnami.com/stack/wordpress/installer), and install it using `--wordpress_instance_name NEW_BLOG_NAME` option.

First, download the module, and then run the download file with a special parameter.

**Windows**

```
shell> ./bitnami-wordpress-VERSION-module-windows-installer.exe --wordpress_instance_name NEW_BLOG_NAME
```

**Linux**

```
$ chmod a+x bitnami-wordpress-VERSION-module-linux-x64-installer.run
$ ./bitnami-wordpress-VERSION-module-linux-x64-installer.run --wordpress_instance_name NEW_BLOG_NAME
```

**Mac OS X**

```
$ hdiutil mount bitnami-wordpress-VERSION-module-osx-x86_64-installer.dmg
$ /Volumes/WordPress\ Module\ VERSION/BitNami\ WordPress\ Module.app/Contents/MacOS/installbuilder.sh --wordpress_instance_name NEW_BLOG_NAME
```

Once you have the module installed, you will be able to access it through http://localhost/NEW_BLOG_NAME

Answer (score 0):

I think the best option to what you need is to use the Multisite Plugin (https://wordpress.org/plugins/multisite-plugin-manager/). 
Bitnami has already a shipped WP Multisite application