# Installing additional Wordpress instances into a Bitnami multi-tier WP stack?

Tags: wordpress, apache, bitnami

I have installed the Bitnami Mutli-tier Wordpress stack (on Azure).

I want to install a number of additional instances of WP onto that stack. Because it is the multi-tier version of the stack, the normal instructions for installing additional WP instances do not work. This is because the MySQL server is on a separate VM, and the Bitnami Wordpress installed is not set up for handling that.

So, instructions such as those [**posted here**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42925377/how-to-install-bitnami-wordpress-inside-a-subdirectory-of-bitnami-wordpress), don't work. The official instructions, which those are a replica of, are [**here**](https://docs.bitnami.com/installer/apps/wordpress/#how-to-install-several-wordpress-modules-on-the-same-stack).

So, what I am wanting to hear from people, is the recommended way to add additional WP instances to this stack. For instance, can I just go ahead and install wordpress the normal way (set up a new directory with the WP source files in it), and then make some manual changes to the Apache and/or vhost conf files so that the new instance is registered on the server? If so, what changes do I need to make to the conf files (etc.) for that?

**Please note**, I am **not** referring to the Bitnami Wordpress **Multisite** stack. It is the **Multi-tier** stack, on which the MySQL server is on a separate VM. Also, I am not interested in using the multisite feature of Wordpress, for various reasons.

Answer (score 1):

[Bitnami Developer here] As you mentioned, you can't follow the official workflow to install several WordPress on top of the same stack when using the Multi-Tier solution.

Bitnami has not developed yet a similar way to install several WP on a Multi-Tier solution. However, I can describe step-by-step what you need to do in order to get your purpose.

- Connect to your Server via SSH as described [here](https://docs.bitnami.com/azure-templates/faq/#connect_ssh).
- Duplicate the WordPress Folder. You can use the commands below:

  ```
  sudo cp -rf /opt/bitnami/wordpress /opt/bitnami/second-wordpress
  sudo cp -rf /bitnami/wordpress/ /bitnami/second-wordpress/
  sudo rm /opt/bitnami/second-wordpress/wp-config.php
  sudo rm /opt/bitnami/second-wordpress/wp-content
  sudo ln -s /bitnami/second-wordpress/wp-config.php /opt/bitnami/second-wordpress/wp-config.php
  sudo ln -s /bitnami/second-wordpress/wp-content /opt/bitnami/second-wordpress/wp-content
  sudo chown -R root:daemon /opt/bitnami/second-wordpress/
  sudo chown -R root:daemon /bitnami/second-wordpress/
  ```
- Configure Apache. This step depends on the Apache Configuration you desire. I supposed you want to have two WP one at: http://YOUR-SERVER-IP/first-wordpress and the second one at http://YOUR-SERVER-IP/second-wordpres.

  - Fist, prepare Apache to use a "Prefix Configuration".

    ```
    sudo mkdir /opt/bitnami/apache/conf/prefix
    sudo mv /opt/bitnami/apache/conf/vhosts/htaccess /opt/bitnami/apache/conf/prefix/htaccess
    sudo cp /opt/bitnami/apache/conf/prefix/htaccess/wordpress-htaccess.conf /opt/bitnami/apache/conf/prefix/htaccess/second-wordpress-htaccess.conf 
    sudo rm /opt/bitnami/apache/conf/vhosts/wordpress-vhost.conf 
    sudo rm /opt/bitnami/apache/conf/vhosts/wordpress-vhost.conf
    ```
  - Create the file `/opt/bitnami/apache/conf/prefix/wordpress-prefix.conf`        with the content below:

    ```
    Alias /first-wordpress/ "/opt/bitnami/wordpress/"
    Alias /first-wordpress "/opt/bitnami/wordpress"
    <Directory "/opt/bitnami/wordpress">
      Options -Indexes +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
      AllowOverride None
      Require all granted
      DirectoryIndex index.html index.php

      RewriteEngine On
      RewriteBase /
      RewriteRule ^index.php$ - [S=1]
      RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
      RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
      RewriteRule . index.php [L]

    </Directory>
    Include /opt/bitnami/apache/conf/prefix/htaccess/wordpress-htaccess.conf
    ```
  - Create the file `/opt/bitnami/apache/conf/prefix/second-wordpress-prefix.conf`        with the content below:

    ```
    Alias /second-wordpress/ "/opt/bitnami/second-wordpress/"
    Alias /second-wordpress "/opt/bitnami/second-wordpress"
    <Directory "/opt/bitnami/second-wordpress">
      Options -Indexes +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
      AllowOverride None
      Require all granted
      DirectoryIndex index.html index.php

      RewriteEngine On
      RewriteBase /
      RewriteRule ^index.php$ - [S=1]
      RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
      RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
      RewriteRule . index.php [L]

    </Directory>
    Include /opt/bitnami/apache/conf/prefix/htaccess/second-wordpress-htaccess.conf
    ```
  - Edit the line below in the file `/opt/bitnami/apache/conf/prefix/htaccess/second-wordpress-htaccess.conf`:

    ```
    <Directory "/opt/bitnami/wordpress/wp-content/plugins/akismet">
    ```
  - with the value:

    ```
    <Directory "/opt/bitnami/second-wordpress/wp-content/plugins/akismet">
    ```
  - Add the lines below in the file `/opt/bitnami/apache/conf/bitnami/bitnami.conf` (both Vhosts behind the line `ErrorDocument 503 /503.html`):

    ```
    Include "/opt/bitnami/apache/conf/prefix/wordpress-prefix.conf"
    Include "/opt/bitnami/apache/conf/prefix/second-wordpress-prefix.conf"
    ```
- Connect to the Database

  ```
  sudo /opt/bitnami/mysql/bin/mysql -u root -h mariadb -p
  ```
- Create a Database for the new WP and grant permissions to `bn_wordpress` user.

  ```
  CREATE DATABASE bitnami_second_wordpress;
  GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON `bitnami_second_wordpress`.* TO 'bn_wordpress'@'%'
  ```
- Edit the lines below at `/opt/bitnami/wordpress/wp-config.php`:

  ```
  define('WP_SITEURL', 'http://' . $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] . '/');
  define('WP_HOME', 'http://' . $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] . '/');
  ```

  with the value:

  ```
  define('WP_SITEURL', 'http://' . $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] . '/first-wordpress');
  define('WP_HOME', 'http://' . $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] . '/first-wordpress');
  ```
- Edit the lines below at `/opt/bitnami/second-wordpress/wp-config.php`:

  ```
  define('DB_NAME', 'bitnami_wordpress');
  define('WP_SITEURL', 'http://' . $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] . '/');
  define('WP_HOME', 'http://' . $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] . '/');
  ```

  with the value:

  ```
  define('DB_NAME', 'bitnami_second_wordpress');
  define('WP_SITEURL', 'http://' . $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] . '/second-wordpress');
  define('WP_HOME', 'http://' . $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] . '/second-wordpress');
  ```
- Finally Restart Apache;

  ```
  sudo nami restart apache
  ```

Comment: Thank you very much Juan. These detailed instructions are super helpful. In my case, I intend for each WP installation to have it's own domain. www.domain1.com, www.domain2.com, etc. Would it be too much to ask what changes are required in these instructions for this scenario?

Comment: You're welcome @inspirednz 
Most of the changes to get that configuration are related with how to configure Apache and the **WP_SITEURL** and **WP_HOME** properties.
I think this is a very specific configuration and we should move this conversation to https://community.bitnami.com/ (a specific forum to talk about this kind of problems). Please open a thread there and I'll be glad to explain you all the details.

Comment: Hi @Juan. Actually, I already have a post on there, which I started prior to this one, and had slow response. It's picked up since then, but your reply above is the clearest in terms of instructions for what I was actually asking about. The post on Bitnami is https://community.bitnami.com/t/seeking-advice-for-multiple-wordpress-apps-on-one-stack-etc/50196/12
I am considering going with the Nginx approach balgaru has suggested. Still making my mind up about that.